# Customize an EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I require adding a little intelligence to the JPA EntityManager, customizing the `createNamedQuery`. 
I'm working in a project build of many modules, where every module annotates its instance of EntityManager with `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "emModuleName")`.

It seems that I cannot simply extends the interface EntityManager, but I don't find any documentation about this matter online.

Does anyone has an idea what is the best solution for my needs?

I cannot extend one specific implementation because the application has to be JPA implementation independent.
Thanks

Comment: Since each JPA provider IMPLEMENTS EntityManager with their own class, and since you say you cannot extend an implementation, then you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create own implementation of `EntityManager` that would act as a wrapper to real `EnityManager`. Intercept required method (in your case `createNamedQuery`), and delegate every other call to underyling object.

OR

Create your own proxies to intercept method calls.

Both ways however are not that trivial to use as you probably would like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BaseEntitymanager which provides a base implementation for basic CRUD services and the respective DAO has to extend the BaseEntityManager.

***BaseEntityManager:***

```
public interface EntityManagerBase<E, K> {
    E create(E entity);
    void delete(E entity);
    E update(E entity);
}
```

***EntityManagerBaseImpl***

```
    public abstract class EntityManagerBaseImpl<E, K> implements
        EntityManagerBase<E, K> {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private TransactionManager txManager;

    private Class<E> type;

    public E create(E entity) {     
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        return entity;
    }
```

***MyDaoImpl:***

```
public class MyDaoImpl extends EntityManagerBaseImpl<MyDBO, Long> implements MyDao {
//put your implementation of methods
}
```